# C# unable to add dynamic key and value to expando object

Tags: c#

I have a dynamic expando object, I am unable to add values into it. I am getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error

```
 public class GameSet
    {

        public GameAttributes Attributes { get; set; }

    }



public class GameAttributes 
    {
        public GameAttributes ()
        {
            dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
            var Attribute = expando as IDictionary<string,string>;
        }

        public IDictionary<string,string> Attribute { get; set; }
    }

 var gameAttributes = new GameAttributes ();
gameAttributes.Attribute.Add(OtherDataModelAttribute.name, OtherAttributeAttribute.value); // Error comes in this line
```

Comment: `Attribute` which is defined as a property is not initialized in the code

Comment: In the constructor you've written var Attribute =  expando as IDictionary<string,string>; You probably just want Attribute = expando as IDictionary<string,string>;

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
var Attribute = expando as IDictionary<string,string>;
```

sets a local variable called `Attribute` inside the constructor. This variable remains unused, so the object gets discarded as soon as the constructor is done processing.

If you want to set property `Attribute`, remone `var`.

Better yet, replace `Attribute` with a computed property:

```
private readonly dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string,object> Attribute => expando as IDictionary<string,string>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign the dynamic expando object to a new object

```
var Attribute = expando as IDictionary<string,string>;
```

not the property of the class.
so

```
public IDictionary<string,string> Attribute { get; set; }
```

is not assigned yet. Thus it throws exception.

try to change you code as

```
public GameAttributes ()
        {
            dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
            this.Attribute = expando as IDictionary<string,string>;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in previous answers, there is bug in constructor (creating local variable with var, instead of assigning to member variable with this.Attribute).

There is another bug.

ExpandoObject cannot be casted to

```
IDictionary<string,string>
```

Instead, it can be casted to:

```
IDictionary<string, object>
```